# messed up ssl for nginx sub-dir with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain, virtualhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

My server hosts several sub-domains :

- one containing a Laravel app : cluego
- a Node.js app : qruzzle
- and another Laravel app: ijsbrekerz

I tried to follow some tutorials to get HTTPS working.

The result is puzzling for me, tutorial-follower :(
Wat I see  now is:

```
When I browse to:

https://cluego.nl              ->    Welcome to NGINX, succesfully installed, need to configure
https://qruzzle.cluego.nl/     ->    Welcome to NGINX, succesfully installed, need to configure
https://ijsbrekerz.cluego.nl/  ->    Welcome to NGINX, succesfully installed, need to configure
www.cluego.nl                  ->    Works great!
qruzzle.cluego.nl              ->    works, not secure
ijsbrekerz.cluego.nl           ->    works, not secure
```

I have to add some paths somewhere but I cannot figure out where since I do not really understand the reverse proxy configuration.
I am afraid to break something because this all was done based of following tutorials.

Can anyone point out where I must add the locations of root, qruzzle, and ijsbrekerz?

The sub-domains are defined in sites-available, for example: /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/qruzzle.cluego.nl

```
# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name qruzzle.cluego.nl www.qruzzle.cluego.nl;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/qruzzle.cluego.nl.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

In ssl.conf I have:

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name cluego.nl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluego.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluego.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    ########################################################################
    # from https://cipherlist.eu/                                            #
    ########################################################################

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;# Requires nginx >= 1.13.0 else use TLSv1.2
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
    ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
    # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    ##################################
    # END https://cipherlist.eu/ BLOCK #
    ##################################

}
```

Comment: Are the HTTP to HTTPS redirections expected to be done by the applications or by NGINX ? Only `www.cluego.nl` seems to have this redirection working, and done on the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

*Non definitive answer as the question lacks some design information.*

The following points must be checked/changed :

- does the certificate contain **all** of the domains (cluego.nl, [www.cluego.nl](http://www.cluego.nl), qruzzle.cluego.nl,..) ? It doesn't look so at first sight.
- `server_name` must contain **all** of the domains, for both `server` blocks if the HTTP to HTTPS should done by the applications
- add `server_name` blocks for each domain if the HTTP to HTTPS redirections must be done by NGINX, and combine that with `return 302` directives.

Comment: Thank for answering. I am afraid I do not understand what you are suggesting, since I do not really understand wehat I am doing.

In one subdomain a laravel applcation runs, in another subdomain a node.js appplication runs. Because the node.js has it's own server I was told to use the reverse proxy. I am not sure what that means exactly.
I followed a tutorial on generating the certificate. I am not sure how to check if all domains are present.

Comment: To begin with (we'll see later for the rest), a certificate is necessary for every **HTTPS** website. Clic on the dock on the left of the URL on your browser, then try to the right menu to display your certificate (menu depends on the browser). You will find a certificate name, and alternative names. See with the one who purchased the certificate(s) and ask if you have all the necessary material (as said, it doesn't look so)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the step-by-step approach. Have been very busy last week, now some time to look into this.. I found the following info: `Certificate issued to Common Name (CN) cluego.nl
Organization (O) <Not Part Of Certificate>
Organizational Unit (OU) <Not Part Of Certificate> `

Comment: I think this is because of the line `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluego.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot` in ssl.conf. How can I adjust that to create certificate for all domains?

Comment: Messed around with certbot, expanded key to use all subdomains. Now every url works, (even https://www.cluego.nl) except for the root `https://cluego.nl` Where must I add something? In sites-available/default? sites-available/cluego.nl?

Comment: Finally solved the issue, by commenting out the server_name in ssl.conf. Seemed to be double configured, also in sites-enabled/default: `server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

#    server_name cluego.nl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluego.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluego.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
`

Comment: good job @M.Koops